# Python: Read a .txt file and change the name of files in directory with .txt index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a directory that contains lots of images and meanwhile, I have a `.txt` file that contains names like in the below format. I would like to change the name of images based on text file titles. There are 100 names and 100 images in a folder.

**Inside Text Files**

```
Flower Blue
Flower Red
Flower Black
Flower orange
```

**Inside Folder**

```
001.mp4
002.mp4
003.mp4
004.mp4
```

**Code** Below code does not change the name

```
import os
import shutil

dirpath = "/media/cvpr/CM_22/inst_you/vidoes"

for file in os.listdir(dirpath):
    with open('/media/cvpr/CM_22/inst_you/vidoes_name') as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
        print(file)
        newfile = os.path.join(dirpath, file.split("_", 1)[1])
        print(newfile)
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, file), newfile)
```

Comment: Note the `os.listdir()` doesn't sort the files so no guarantee which file is renamed without sorting it first.  If the files are numbered 001-100 just generate the names instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input.txt` contains the new file names and they are the names of corresponding files 001.mp4, 002.mp4, etc., using the `pathlib` module already provided in Python is more straightforward:

```py
from pathlib import Path

with open('input.txt') as names:
    # Read and number lines starting from 1.
    for i, line in enumerate(names, 1):
        # Generate original filename (001.mp4, 002.mp4, etc.)
        p = Path(f'{i:03d}.mp4')
        # .with_stem() replaces the base name of file
        p.rename(p.with_stem(line.strip()))
```

Comment: I realized that i have copy python script inside folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the **for** inside the **with**, and use ***zip*** to generate one new filename and one old filename each time.
It should be something like:

```
with open('/media/cvpr/CM_22/inst_you/vidoes_name') as f:  
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
        for old_filename, new_filename in zip(os.listdir(dirpath), lines):
            print(old_filename)
            print(new_filename)
            newfile = os.path.join(dirpath, new_filename.split("_", 1)[1])
            print(newfile)
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, old_filename), newfile)
```

Comment: It doesn't work my file name is "XX -XXX (dddd)" so i have removed split function and modify it os.path.join(dirpath, new_filename) but it gives an error  os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, file), newfile)
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: @KhawarIslam i have misused the variable name, change it from file to old_filename